# Api Nodejs jwt-Simple

Tags: nodejs, jwt

estoy armando una api con nodejs, y quiero incluir los token con jwt-simple, puedo crear token y usarlo para acceder a las rutas, pero cuando quiere comprobar la expiración del token directamente salta por el cath de error de 'invalid token'. como puedo solucionarlo?

App.js

`router.get("/Producto/:id",auth,(req,res)=>{
    ProductoModel.findById(req.params.id).populate('Iddetalle').exec((err,respuesta)=>{
        if(err) res.send({estado:{codigo:0,respuesta:err.message}});
        res.send({estado:{codigo:0,respuesta:'Operacion Buscar exitosa '}, Producto:respuesta});
        console.log('Operacion Buscar exitosa');
    })
});`

auth.js

```
'use strict'
var service = require('../service');


function isAuth(req,res, next){

    if(!req.headers.authorization){
        return res.status(403).send({message:'No tienes autorización'});
    }
    var token=req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    service.decodeToken(token).then(response=>{
        req.user=response;
        next();
    }).catch(reject=>{
        res.status(reject.status).send({message:reject.message})
        next();
    })
}

module.exports= isAuth;
```

service.js

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var moment = require('moment');
var config = require('../config');

function CrearToken(estudianteModel){
    var payload = {
        sub:estudianteModel._id,
        Nombre:estudianteModel.Nombre,
        Apellido:estudianteModel.Apellido,
        Legajo:estudianteModel.Legajo,
        Password:estudianteModel.Password,
        IdCarrera:estudianteModel.IdCarrera,
        iat:moment().unix(),
        exp: moment().add(2,"minutes").unix()
     };
     return jwt.encode(payload,config.SECRET_TOKEN) 
}

function decodeToken(token){
    var decode=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        try {
            var payload=jwt.decode(token,config.SECRET_TOKEN);
            if(payload.exp<=moment().unix()){
                reject({
                    status:401,
                    message:'Token Expirado'
                });
            }
            else{
            console.log('payload.sub', payload.sub);
            resolve(payload.sub);}
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject({
                status:501,
                message:'invalid token'
            });
        }
    })
    console.log('defen:', decode);
    return decode;
}

module.exports= {CrearToken,decodeToken}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun tu código, el valor que le das a la expiración es un Unix timestamp y los formatos que acepta la propiedad 'expireIn' tienen que ir expresado con el numero de segundos o una cadena que describe un intervalo de tiempo 'zeit/ms'.

> expiresIn: expresado en segundos o una cadena que describe un intervalo de tiempo zeit / ms .
>   Por ejemplo: 60, "2 days", "10h", "7d". Un valor numérico se interpreta como un recuento de segundos. Si usa una cadena, asegúrese de proporcionar las unidades de tiempo (días, horas, etc.), de lo contrario se usa la unidad de milisegundos de forma predeterminada ( "120"es igual a "120ms").

Fuente: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim

Espero que esto solucione tu error.

Saludos